# add observable<myObject> to observable <myObject[]>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

I am using a observable of myObject array to populate a input type select in my html template.
I want to be able to add another option to my list depending conditions.

=> I want to add `myItem = Observable <myObject>` to my `myList = Observable<myObject[]>`

I retreive both observables from http methods.
I cannot find any operator to do this in the docs.

I am able to to this with a subscription to myItem like this

```
myList.pipe(
 map(x=> myItem.subscribe(y=> x.push(y)))
)
```

But I would prefer to do this without subscription.

my template is like

````
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [value]="selected$ | async" (selectionChange)="getSelectedValue($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of myList | async" [value]="item.Id">{{item.Name}} </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Observable.concat`:

```
myList = Observable.concat(myList, from(myItem));
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html

Answer (score 1):

// RxJS v6+

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs';

myList = concat(myList, from(myItem))
```